# Pandas read_csv specify AWS Profile

Tags: python, pandas, python-s3fs

Pandas (v1.0.5) use `s3fs` library to connect with AWS S3 and read data. By default, s3fs uses the credentials found in `~/.aws/credentials` file in `default` profile. How do I specify which profile should pandas use while reading a CSV from S3?

Eg.

```py
s3_path = 's3://mybucket/myfile.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(s3_path)
```

```sh
$ cat ~/.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ABCD
aws_secret_access_key = XXXX
[profile2]
aws_access_key_id = PQRS
aws_secret_access_key = YYYY
[profile3]
aws_access_key_id = XYZW
aws_secret_access_key = ZZZZ
```

**Edit :**

Current hack/working solution :

```py
import botocore
import s3fs
session = botocore.session.Session(profile='profile2')
s3 = s3fs.core.S3FileSystem(anon=False, session=session)
df = pd.read_csv( s3.open(path_to_s3_csv) )
```

The only issue with above solution is you need to import 2 different libraries and instantiate 2 objects. Keeping the question open to see if there is another cleaner/simple method.

Comment: I believe you are going to have to use boto3 to download the csv file and then call `pd.read_csv()` on it.

Comment: Yes that's one way. I am trying to see if it is possible to read_csv without downloading it locally.

Answer (score 9):

```
df = pd.read_csv(s3_path, storage_options=dict(profile='profile2'))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to use one profile, setting the environment variable "AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE" works:

```
import os
os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE"] = "profile2"
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_s3_csv)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False, profile_name="your-profile-name")
```

I believe to not use boto, you can use this S3FileSystem part of the s3fs. Then with a file handler something like:

```
with s3.open('bucket/file.txt', 'rb') as f:
```

Comment: I am not sure `profile_name ` is a keyword arg. https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#s3fs.core.S3FileSystem

Comment: It doesn't but it does accept a boto3 session as a parameter, and you can create your `session` with the `profile_name` and then pass it in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is "better" but it seems to be working for me using boto3 directly without needing to use `s3fs` or set an env variable.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3_session = boto3.Session(profile_name="profile_name")
s3_client = s3_session.client("s3")
df = pd.read_csv(s3_client.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key ='key.csv').get('Body'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to configure your .aws/config file:

```
import pandas as pd
import s3fs

KEY_ID = 'xxxx'
ACCESS_KEY = 'yyyy'
BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
fp = 's3://my-bucket/test/abc.csv'


fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False, key=KEY_ID, secret=ACCESS_KEY)
with fs.open(fp) as f:
   df = pd.read_csv(f)
```